# How to determine SQL latency using Hibernate @Formula Annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I am attempting to determine the SQL call latency of several functions that use the @Formula annotation. I am under the assumption that the contents of the @Formula annotation are run prior to entering the function that is attached to, therefore using endTime - startTime would not make sense. Is this accurate?

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this? I am in a corporate environment and unfortunately cannot tinker with any config files.

If it matters, we are using Oracle RDS and Java.

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "SQL Latency".  You won't be able to distinguish network time from parse time from execution time, which means the numbers you get will be rather meaningless.

Comment: Sorry if I was vague. I was mainly thinking execution time of the query against the DB. However I've noticed that some queries that use this @Formula annotation return several MB of data and thus network transfer time is also a concern. Is there any way at all to discern execution/network latency for these calls? Thanks.

Comment: Not on the client.  You need access to the server admin interface, which has all the information you need.

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no way to do this without access to the RDS cli.